# Overwriting existing Tags using ExifTool

Tags: c#, .net, exif, exiftool

I'm currently using the following code to add tags to an image using exiftool.
This works fine.But when the image already has tags,they are not replaced.

```
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = "exiftool.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "-m -stay_open True -@ " + tempDirectory + "\\commands.txt";
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                Process processTemp = new Process();
                processTemp.StartInfo = startInfo;
                processTemp.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                processTemp.Start();
                return true;
```

**Writing commands to a text file that is monitored by exiftool**

```
 writer = new FileInfo(tempDirectory + "commands.txt").AppendText();

  writer.WriteLine("-subject=" + tempstring);
                            writer.WriteLine(outdir + "\\" + x.Value.ElementAt(0) + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(x.Key));
                            writer.WriteLine("-overwrite_original");
                            if (counter != files.Count)
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine("-execute");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine("-stay_open");
                                writer.WriteLine("False");
                            }
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of c#/.net, but you seem to be addressing two different files.  In the first bit of code, you have `tempDirectory + "\\commands.txt" but in the second, it's `tempDirectory + "commands.txt"`  Does `tempDirectory` have the trailing backslash in the second usage?

Comment: @StarGeek Yes.. it does.The tags are getting added but for some images with existing tags,the tags are not updated.